# Запуск консольного приложения в новой консоли (Windows BAT)

Tags: windows, bat

Требуется запустить консольное приложение в новой консоли, но не закрывать консоль после завершения программы, а дождаться ввода с клавиатуры. Как это можно сделать? При использовании команды start консоль закрывается по завершению работы программы.

Comment: Возможно, подойдет такой вариант: start cmd /k qwerty.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извините, если слишком прямо понял вопрос, но использование `pause` в конце не поможет?

```
start test.bat
pause
```

**Добавил еще вариант**

```
echo off
start test.bat
set /p input=""
```

тогда будет ожидание ввода каких-нибудь символов и/или нажатия ввода.

**И еще вариант**

```
start /WAIT test.bat
```

**И последний вариант, наверное самый удачный и нужный вам**

```
start /b test.bat && pause
```

В таком варианте выполняется `test.bat` в том же терминале и постановка на паузу после исполнения скрипта. К примеру так выглядит запуск этой команды:

```
C:\Users\zombic>start /b cmd /K "ping localhost && exit" && pause
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
Обмен пакетами с game-desktop [::1] с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от ::1: время<1мс
Ответ от ::1: время<1мс
Ответ от ::1: время<1мс
Ответ от ::1: время<1мс

Статистика Ping для ::1:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
    (0% потерь)
Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
    Минимальное = 0мсек, Максимальное = 0 мсек, Среднее = 0 мсек
```

далее ожидается нажатие любой клавиши.